# How to run a program as another user and add arguments in powershell?

Tags: powershell, runas, start-process

We have a program that only updates when being run with the switch `/t` from an administrator account.

I came up with the CMD prompt version, but I'm new to powershell and having a hard time translating it to Powershell.

The CMD version is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:ourdomain\ouruseracct "C:\Program Files (x86)\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify\ProjectNotify.exe /t"
```

So far I got:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:ourdomain\ouruseracct /savecred "powershell -c start-process -FilePath \"'C:\Program Files (x86)\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify\ProjectNotify.exe'\" -verb runAs"
```

Which runs powershell as admin and starts the program as admin but we need to pass the argument `-t` or `/t` to `projectnotify.exe` when running it.

I believe we need to make use of the `-argumentlist` but not sure how to word it.

I tried

```
$t = "-t"
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify\projectnotify.exe" -ArgumentList $t -Verb runas
```

Which runs the program but not sure if that's how you pass the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Extra work (troubleshooting):

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$ProcInfo = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo'

$ProcInfo.Domain = $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
$ProcInfo.UserName = $Cred.UserName
$ProcInfo.Password = $Cred.Password
$ProcInfo.FileName = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify\ProjectNotify.exe"
$ProcInfo.Arguments = '/t'
$ProcInfo.WorkingDirectory = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify"
$ProcInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Normal
$ProcInfo.Verb = 'RunAs'
$ProcInfo.UseShellExecute = $true

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($ProcInfo)
```

---

After some more thought, here's a simpler way (in a single command even):

```
Start-Job -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {
    $Dir = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify"

    $StartArgs = @{
        'FilePath' = "$Dir\ProjectNotify.exe"
        'ArgumentList' = '/t'
        'Verb' = 'RunAs'
        'WindowStyle' = 'Normal'
        'WorkingDirectory' = $Dir
        'PassThru' = $true
    }
    Start-Process @StartArgs
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

My previous answer is at the bottom of this post now.

---

References:

- [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0)
- [Get-Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-3.0)
- [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-3.0)
- [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job?view=powershell-3.0)

Extra reading:

- [Import-CliXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml?view=powershell-3.0)
- [Export-CliXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-3.0)

  ---

Assuming an on-demand script, you should create a `pscredential` object if you want to natively run this from powershell:

***`Launch.cmd`***

```
SET "PS=%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
SET "SCRIPT=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Path\to\wrapper.ps1"

%PS% -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%SCRIPT%"
```

***`wrapper.ps1`***

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

# To avoid prompting every time:
#
# if (-not (Test-Path -Path '.\mycred.xml')) {
#     Get-Credential | Export-CliXml -Path '.\mycred.xml'
# }
# $Cred = Import-CliXml -Path '.\mycred.xml'

$StartArgs = @{
    'FilePath' = "$PSHOME\powershell.exe"
    'ArgumentList' = '-NoProfile', '-NoLogo', '-File', '.\runas.ps1'
    'Credential' = $Cred
}
Start-Process @StartArgs
```

***`runas.ps1`***

```
$StartArgs = @{
    'FilePath' = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify\ProjectNotify.exe"
    'ArgumentList' = '/t'
    'Verb' = 'RunAs'
}
Start-Process @StartArgs
```

Comment: Hey, really appreciate the reply. It looks like you understood the question really well. Running that gives an error:

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The requested operation requires elevation.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\ProjectMatrix\ProjectNotify\runas.ps1:7 char:1
+ Start-Process @StartArgs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Thanks, it runs and asks for credentials then runs both powershell windows with no errors but doesn't run the program. Confused..

Comment: When running the simpler one I get cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
but also no program opens.

Comment: Only GUI. No console.

Comment: Thanks, it still didn't run but returns:
 cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                    
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                                    
     20       3      396       1812       0.03   5512   2 ProjectNotify

Comment: @da64u OK, so the process **is** launching as your other account, but apparently isn't visible to the account you're launching powershell with.

Comment: hmm, even when trying my account I don't see it. If I'm on a domain whats the correct format to type in the credentials? I'm trying DOMAIN\USER

Comment: @da64u Yes, that's the right way.  I added more code for you to try now (hopefully this is the silver bullet)

Comment: Same thing, tried multiple accounts but it doesn't run. Thanks for trying. I've been looking at this all week.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question asks for arguements, but if you don't them, this works:

```
Start cmd.exe -Verb RunAs
```

You can also run this using the 'Run' window or search box:

```
powershell -command start cmd.exe -verb runas
```